# Unobvious deadlock situation

Tags: go, synchronization

Could you please explain why this deadlock happens ?

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    m := sync.RWMutex{}
    go func(){
        m.RLock()
        runtime.Gosched()
        m.RLock()
        m.RUnlock()
        m.RUnlock()
    }()

    runtime.Gosched()
    m.Lock()
    m.Unlock()

    fmt.Println("works")
}
```

It's non obvious to me why this deadlock <del>always</del> mostly happen. <del>Could this be a quirk of the scheduler ?</del>

Comment: It does not happen always. Your statement has no proof. I tried it, and was able to "squeeze" a run where it printed `"works"`. This question as-is doesn't seem very thoughtful. P.S. The Go Playground caches the output and does not run the code again. I tested it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the RWMutex doc:

> If a goroutine holds a RWMutex for reading and another goroutine might
>   call Lock, **no goroutine should expect to be able to acquire a read
>   lock until the initial read lock is released**. In particular, this
>   prohibits recursive read locking. This is to ensure that the lock
>   eventually becomes available; a blocked Lock call excludes new readers
>   from acquiring the lock.

So what's going on in your code when deadlock occurs:

1. first RLock()
2. Lock() // this call waits until first Rlock()  released and blocks calls to future Rlocks()
3. Rlock() // this call waits until Lock() is released

Comment: So this is a write-preferring RW lock. Am I right ?

Comment: I guess, you are.